# issue while installing Square nuget pacge in visual stdio

Tags: c#, nuget, square

Error       Could not install package 'Square 4.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

**i face this issue on version 4.5 , all version of square not installed on this version of website**

Comment: `i face this issue on version 4.5` don't use 4.5 then. Especially not with a payment service that *demands* TLS1.2 and higher. The earliest supported .NET Old version may be 4.5.2, but only 4.7.2 and later use both TLS1.2 automatically and solve the .NET Standard compatibility issues. You can use 4.6 to use TLS1.2 automatically, but you'd still get compatibility problems with .NET Standard 2 NuGet packages. By now, almost all NuGet packages target .NET Standard 2

Comment: In any case, your clients/customers won't be running 4.5. You aren't using 4.5 either.  Installing a newer 4.x version replaces any previous ones. Installing a newer version through Windows Update will replace any older versions fo example. So will installing any Visual Studio version since VS 2015

Answer (score 0):

If you check the page for that package over on [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Square/4.0.0) you'll see that it is built against .NET Standard 1.3. If you then check what .NET version that corresponds to over on [Microsofts documentation for .NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) you'll also see that .NET Standard corresponds to .NET 4.6. So you can't install this package in a project that targets .NET 4.5.

Also, it is the same requirements for Square 8.1.0 so you should probably get that version instead of 4.0.0.